# PID control implementation problem in MATLAB/Simulink

Tags: power-electronics

I am developing a non-isolated DC-DC converter project with LCL resonant network using GaN FETs.

Features of the circuit:

- Bidirectional 200V-400V converter
- 100kHz switching frequency
- 1kW rated output power and 0.5 duty cycle
- 100ns dead time is applied in the open loop system

When I add PID control, I think I cannot apply PWM voltage to the MOSFETs. No matter how much I change the PID control values of the system, the system output does not change and does not reach the desired value. I can't understand what I'm missing.

Here is my circuit implementation:

[image: Simulation Circuit]

The output voltage is labelled 'A' in the circuit. It should be around 400V DC:

[image]

Here are the other parameters of the blocks in the simulation of the converter in MATLAB if it's necessary.

Here is the PWM generator block parameters

[image]

Here is the half bridge driver block parameters:

[image]

I can provide additional information if necessary.

Comment: Is there a way to temporarily disable/ignore the PID and simply apply a fixed dc bias at the input of the PWM block? That way, you could already check the whole chain operates ok (should deliver a raw dc voltage whose level depends on the dc bias you'll apply to PWM input). When it works, you can go back to the PID block.

Comment: hi verbal, thank you for your concern. Without PID, circuit is working fine, reaching 1kW output power and getting 400V. So I tried it, but the settling time was too long without PID Control, so I tried PID control.  However, when I applied PID control, I could not apply a proper PWM signal to the FETs from the PID control output.  So I probably made a few adjustments wrong, because obviously while a PWM Signal (PID Controlled) is always active, the complementary Pwm signal remains at 0V.

Comment: If the PFC works well with a dc setpoint, then the PID block seems causing problems. Either its output voltage is too high when it rails up at startup or the coefficients are wrongly set. I would recommend you compensate your dc-dc with a type 2 or 3 compensator first, with the poles and zeroes on hand, then determine the corresponding PID coefficients. See my [APEC 2021](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202021.pdf) on PID slide 52. Using this approach avoids going through trial and errors for setting the PID up.

Comment: You have continuous time and discrete times modules, perhaps you should adjust sampling time somewhere in your continuous time. Or maybe use PID(z) which is more appropiate.